# Capture Flash video from a website

Tags: internet-explorer, website, video-capture

I am looking for a software which I can copy Flash video from a particular website.

I tried several capture apps but none can retrieve the .swf file from this particular website:

> http://www.obtampons.ca/apology

Software I tried:

- Replay Media Catcher
- CoCoSoft Streamdwn

but none works, any idea?

Comment: You used the video-capture tag and list software for capturing online video streams, but you talk about retrieving a .swf file. So what are you trying to do? Because .swf are Flash animations, not streaming video. A site may use Flash to embed a video player on their page. But the .swf file is just the video player. It streams the video from a separate (usually .mp4) file via RTMP or HTTP.

Comment: I mean to capture the video, which is flash, I wasn't able to do so.

Comment: This website uses a flash, but it has programming inside, when  you enter your name, then the flash will write your name in the flash, every capture software will not work here, you can even try that and see. in This case I will need a video capturing software that capture video/audio, this is why I tagged as video-capture because it is not regular flash website.

Comment: That's the thing though. Video capture software are designed to capture video streams (a sequence of video frames/images + audio data). A Flash animation isn't actually a video. It's a scripted animation (the file stores different vector objects and image files + scripting that tells Flash player how to move these objects/images). It's also not streamed, the entire .swf file is downloaded and then it runs in the Flash player. So video capture programs won't know what to do with a Flash animation.

Comment: It's like the difference between a video reel versus a puppet show. The video reel projects a sequence of images to animate objects on the screen, whereas a puppet show actually has objects that people move and animate in real-time. You can make a video of a puppet show, but you need a camcorder to do so. To turn Flash video into a video file, you need to export it from Flash as a rendered video or use a screen capture program to capture the video from your desktop.

Comment: @Miroco you should create an answer referencing Snagit and mark that as correct so people know this problem has been solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the HTML source of the page, the embedded JS shows a URI for an XML file:

```
    // FLASH VARS       
    var flashvars = {};     
    flashvars.language = 'en';
    flashvars.xmlPath = '/sites/default/files/xml/';
    flashvars.appXMLPath = 'app.xml';
    flashvars.name = name;
    flashvars.ga = 'UA-6548511-7'; // DO NOTCHANGE
    // FLASH PARAMETERS
    var params = {};
    // FLASH ATTRIBUTES
    params.wmode = 'opaque';
    var attributes = {};
    attributes.id = 'app';
    attributes.name = 'app';            
    attributes.align = 'middle';
    // SWF OBJECT EMBED
   swfobject.embedSWF("/sites/default/files/app.swf", "flashContent", ...
```

If you put all the parts together, you [get the URL](http://www.obtampons.ca/sites/default/files/xml/app.xml):

```
http://www.obtampons.ca/sites/default/files/xml/app.xml
```

XML files like these are usually used by Flash embeds to store configuration files. For embedded video players, they usually contain the actual video file that the player streams. Usuaully, these are straight MP4 or FLV files, but in this case, the video is designed to inject the user's name into parts of the video (the song title on the sheet music and other places). This can't be done in regular videos, so a .swf animation is shown instead, which has an embedded video + some Flash text overlaid on the video to look like it's part of the original video.

If you don't care about the custom name insertion, you can grab [the .SWF animation](http://obmedia.cachefly.net/video/video-withsound.swf) at:

```
http://obmedia.cachefly.net/video/video-withsound.swf
```

This won't actually play in any video players, but if you have Flash player installed you can play it with that, or use your browser's Flash plugin. Once you've opened it with Flash player, you have to right click on the video and hit "Play" to actually start the embedded video.

If you want the whole shebang (the intro Flash animation, the input box asking for your name, your name overlaid over the sheet music in the music video, etc.), then you'll need to grab the actual web page plus all of these files:

```
http://obmedia.cachefly.net/video/video-withsound.swf
http://www.obtampons.ca/sites/default/files/assets/fonts/rose/rosepedals.swf
http://www.obtampons.ca/sites/default/files/assets/fonts/skywriting/skywriting.swf
http://www.obtampons.ca/sites/default/files/assets/fonts/tattoo/tattoo.swf
http://www.obtampons.ca/sites/default/files/xml/app.xml
```

And you'll also need to edit the XML file and the web page to point to the right locations.

If you want an actual video file you can play in a regular video player, you'll need some way to extract it from `video-withsound.swf` or you'll need to use a screen capture tool to record a video of your screen while the music video is playing in Flash player. However, the output will have very low quality relative to file size.

---

If you just want the music video, a far better solution is to simply use a regular video capture tool to capture [this Vimeo version of the video](http://vimeo.com/33449844) which has been customized for the name "Jenna".

*And, yes, I do feel ridiculous for investing so much time investigating an apology video made by Johnson & Johnson over the recall of their heavy flow tampons.*

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: You are amazing!!!! if I could I would give you at least 100 points!!! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

There is a really easy and simple add-on for Firefox, it's called: [Sothink SWF catcher](http://download.cnet.com/Sothink-SWF-Catcher-for-Firefox/3000-11745_4-10682100.html). This will probably do the job, I have used it before.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work on that particular flash animation with programming... it will work for simple websites but not here. I was able to get it using Snagit software, it has video & Audio option. http://www.techsmith.com/.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try **Internet Download Manager**.(It is a paid software)

It normally can download videos off any website without hassle...

and if you have the swf file, GOM player might be able to play it(this one is free)..